# How can I resize my image based on available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this text that can take as many space as it needs and I have this image that can only get the remaning width.

**If text is small, the image can be large**

**If text is large, the image has to be small**

[image: Small text]
[image: Large text]

I tried with expanded on the image, but then the text gets overflowed

Comment: Could you try to use a Flexible widget?

Comment: i would suggest Flexible and Expanded for widgets.

Answer (score 0):

If you can constraint the width of the image into a constrainted box, you can wrap the text inside an expanded like this,

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        "Foo foo",
      ),
    ),
    Image.asset("assets/images/image.jpg"),
  ],
);
```

If you dont want to fix the image width (in dip), then you could just wrap both them in seperate expandeds like,

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: Text(
        "Foo foo",
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/image.jpg",
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

And you could checkout all the fit enums [here](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html).

Comment: The first suggestion will always give all the available space to the text, leaving the image pressed agains't the end of the Row, and the second suggestion will fix the proportions rather than let the text size dictates

Comment: What if your text has more than 1 line? if you want to confine your text to 1 or more lines with constrainted width, you can first wrap the text into `AutoSizeText` and wrap this widget in a `FittedBox`

Ref:
AutoSizeText => https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text